# Getting origin mismatch for iFrame in Google Auth for Google sites

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-sites, google-gadget

I have a Google sites which has a custom built gadget. I have a Google login for the same and it gets data from a specific spreadsheet. It works fine for one single gadget included in a page without setting an origin in Google Developer's Console. However, when I insert the gadget into another page of the same Google sites; it gives me an origin mismatch error in the console.

FYI, Google renders each gadget as an iframe.

Please help me with this.

Comment: What do you mean a "custom built gadget"? XML, Apps Script, ...?

Comment: Custom built gadget meaning .. a gadget built by me which delivers some work on Google site. It was written in XML.